# How to add a hidden field to a form with ajaxForm before it goes to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, csrf, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to add a hidden field with its corresponding value to a form (for CSRF protection) whenever it is submitted with the JQuery method: ajaxForm. But I am just getting familiar with front-end and I am struggling to come up with the right javascript for this. Has anybody done that?

Comment: Please add your codes ?

Comment: you can use: `data
An object containing extra data that should be submitted along with the form.` example: `data: { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use beforeSerialize hook to inject the hidden field in the DOM like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/myActionUrl" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myTextBox" value="test" />
    <input id="submitBtn" type="button" onclick="submitThis(this)" value="Submit">
</form>

function submitThis(btnSubmit) {
    $('#' + btnSubmit.form.id).ajaxSubmit({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: onBeforeSubmit,
        beforeSerialize: onBeforeSerialize
    });
    return true;
}

function onBeforeSerialize($form, options) {
    if($('input:hidden[name=myHiddenField]').length == 0) {
        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', "myHiddenField")
            .attr('value', "val")
            .appendTo('#myForm');
    }
}

function onBeforeSubmit(formData, jqForm, options) {    
    var queryString = $.param(formData);
    alert('Querystring: \n' + queryString + '\n');
    return true;
}
```